# Table view cell images change after searching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am working on table view cell containing different images on accessory view and data(text)on left side for each cell.Initially all cells are occupied by its relevant data and images.But when i search on searchdisplaycontroller ,the images are allocated as in new array.
for ex ;I have table view rows containing images of train ,bus ,airplane with the respective texts.But when i search for Bus ,text appears fine but imageview shows irrelevant image (say image of train).
What may be the logic to achieve the above requirement.Im using following code to configure the cell

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    btnImage = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];
    btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(688, 0, 80, 80);
    [btnImage setBackgroundImage:[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnImage addTarget:nil action:@selector(DishImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:btnImage];
    btnImage.tag = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"image clicked at index :%i",btnImage.tag);

}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                 reuseIdentifier:strCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    // assign text for the table view 
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {

        cell.textLabel.text = [arrSearhResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    else      
    {
        // add image button 
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrAllItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
             }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please post the configureCell method, I think the issue is with that method.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the cells are reused, you need to clear the contents when the condition `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` is met.

If you could reference the imageview or the button inside your cell, just clear the image.

Comment: iam unable to take the array of searched images with respect to its array of data ,so that i can display  it after searched screen is shown.

Comment: my prob is not reusing of cells,my prob is actually getting the right image for right data after searching.